# Which Postgres version compatibilty with JDBC Driver 42.1.4?

Tags: postgresql

I am running Keycloak server 3.4.3.Final version, that it used JDBC_POSTGRES_VERSION=42.1.4. I want to know which latest Postgres version (10,11,12,13) will compatibility with 42.1.4 driver.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392170/does-a-jdbc-drivers-version-and-a-dbs-version-have-to-match-exactly. TL;DR: the current 42.2.22 driver support PostgreSQL 8.2+ and in general you should use the latest driver, but using a recent driver for an older database should also work.

Comment: [Quote from the driver's homepage](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/about/about.html) "*The current version of the driver should be compatible with PostgreSQL 8.2 and higher, and Java 6 (JDBC 4.0), Java 7 (JDBC 4.1), Java 8 (JDBC 4.2) and Java 9.*"

Comment: For compatibility information see [Downloads](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)

Comment: @rieckpil: My question is used JDBC version 42.1.4. I could not upgrade to newer versions. 

Adrian Klaver: The Link to downloads is the current version of the driver, it is not the compatibility between JDBC version and Postgres server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the JDBC driver 42.1.4 being released on the 1st of August 2017 (2017-08-01) according to the [changelog](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html), you can take a look at the state of the release/download page of Postgres at that time using e.g. the Internet Archive.

A page [snapshot from November 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114223005/https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) (some month after the release) reads the following:

Current Version 42.1.4

> This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual
> requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver
> you should be using. It supports PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer and requires
> Java 6 or newer. It contains support for SSL and the javax.sql
> package.
>
> ```
> If you are using Java 8 or newer then you should use the JDBC 4.2 version.
> If you are using Java 7 then you should use the JDBC 4.1 version.
> If you are using Java 6 then you should use the JDBC 4.0 version.
> If you are using a Java version older than 6 then you will need to use a JDBC3 version of the driver, which will by necessity not be
> ```
>
> current, found in Other Versions.

TL;DR: You can use this driver starting with PostgreSQL 8.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yoru feedback. I have been using Postgres 9.4 + JDBC driver 42.1.4 + Java 8 since some years ago, and for now it still working fine. My target is which Postgres version (10, 11, 12, 13) can be worked with JDBC driver 42.1.4 + Java 8.

Comment: You can use **any** PostgreSQL starting from version 8.2. So use the latest PostgreSQL version if you want or version 10 or 11 or 12. As I see it, there is **no** compatibility matrix if you expect such.

Answer (score 1):

**PostgreSQL release history:**
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/
https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

**PostgreSQL JDBC release history:**
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html